# Refresh activity on phone wakeup?

Tags: android, android-activity

In the case where the user suspends the phone when an activity is shown, and then later resumes the phone with the activity shown, I'd like to refresh the data.  But the onStart() does not get called in this case.  Is there an equivalent event to override for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onResume?

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume()
       {
         super.onResume();
        //stuff that needs to be restarted
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Read this over and over until you really understand and remember it: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

It will pay off to you, believe me! ;)

Comment: I'm very familiar with that document, but no where does it mention the case of the phone display being turned off while the activity is still in the foreground..

Comment: When your display goes off, yo will receive 
onPause. 
After display goes on, you will receive 
onRestart->onStart, 
and upon unlocking phone, 
onResume